Error executing JNLP file with Open Web Start
I have an old Applet that is using Java Web Start.
To launch this Applet, I use this JNLP file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" codebase="http://11.161.4.122:7777/aw_htm/">
  <information>
    <title>Webstart Oracle Forms</title>
    <vendor>www.testtest.it</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.testtest.it/"/>
    <description>Webstart Oracle Forms</description>
  <icon kind="shortcut" href="http://11.161.4.122/aw_htm/AW_3.ico" />
  <shortcut online="true">
  <desktop />
  <menu submenu="Avvio vvvvvv" />
  </shortcut>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.6.0+"/>
    <jar href="frmallIM_runtimeHalt.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <jar href="awsicon.jar"/>
    <jar href="yyy-pjc-core.jar"/>
    <jar href="yyy-pjc-util-print.jar"/>
    <jar href="yyy-pjc-anpr-samlgenerator.jar"/>
    <jar href="frmwebutil.jar"/>
    <jar href="FormsGraph.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="Webstart Oracle Forms" main-class="oracle.forms.engine.Main" width="990" height="660">
    <param name="background" value="sfondo11g-dark.jpg"/>
    <param name="logo" value="logomim.gif"/>
    <param name="serverApp" value="default"/>
    <param name="lookAndFeel" value="oracle"/>
    <param name="allow_debug" value="true"/>
    <param name="separateFrame" value="true"/>
    <param name="em_mode" value="1"/>
    <param name="latencyCheck" value="true"/>
    <param name="networkRetries" value="240"/>
    <param name="serverArgs" value="escapeParams=true module=A00LOGIN.fmx userid=  debug=no host= port= jvmcontroller=yyyweb buffer_records=no debug_messages=no array=no obr=no query_only=no quiet=yes render=no record= tracegroup= log= term=/home2/xxx/lib/xxx.res P_SEPARATEFRAME=true P_ADRS= P_ALIAS=xx P_IDSSO= P_AMBIENTE= P_ENTE= P_LINGUA= P_APPLICAZIONE= P_HTTPHOST=11.161.4.122:7777"/>
    <param name="serverURL" value="http://11.161.4.122:7777/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=http://11.161.4.122:7777/forms/frmservlet?config=yyyWEBJPI_8&#38;ifsessid=WLS_FORMS.formsapp.999&#38;acceptLanguage=it-IT;"/>
    <param name="colorScheme" value="teal"/>
    <param name="splashScreen" value="prodotto.gif"/>
    <param name="clientDPI" value="96"/>
    <param name="dontTruncateTabs" value="true"/>
  </applet-desc>
</jnlp>

I need to run the Applet with a technology that isn't obsolete or deprecated (yeah, I know I'm using an Applet, but my company has to mantain this product).
I've been recommanded to use Open Web Start, because it's still being mantained and updated and can, also, be an alternative to Java Web Start.
I installed it and I tried to run the JNLP file with it but I receive this error:
[ITW-CORE][2024-06-20 16:22:45.064 CEST][DEBUG][com.openwebstart.proxy.direct.DirectProxyProvider] Using NO_PROXY for http://11.161.4.122:7777/aw_htm/netscape/javascript/JSException.class
[ITW-CORE][2024-06-20 16:22:45.119 CEST][ERROR][net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher]
General Throwable encountered:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: netscape/javascript/JSException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:565)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplet(Launcher.java:489)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.access$400(Launcher.java:72)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:665)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: netscape.javascript.JSException
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.lambda$loadClass$9(JNLPClassLoader.java:1452)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(JNLPClassLoader.java:1452)
    ... 8 more

I run everything on Java 8.
Is it something in the configuration? Is Open Web Start not compatible with this JNLP or Applet?

Modern browsers no longer support JDK 8 plugins. The reason for NoClassDefFoundError: netscape/javascript/JSException is because plugin.jar cannot be found, but modern browsers no longer support JDK plugin, so it will not find plugin.jar .

Try to change it to a programming method and replace netscape.javascript.JSException with java.lang.Exception.

@life888888 I updated the log, I forgot a line (the first one): the problem is that it's searching that class in the server that hosts the Applet, but there's nothing like it.
You're telling me I should open the Open Web Start project and modify it to change this?

You've got a tough one here. That applet probably interacts with the web page into which it's embedded, hence the presence of the Netscape API. So you've a double problem right away: a. the applet expects a browser so probably won't work if it doesn't find on and b. even if there is a browser, a modern one won't support it. It's just about possible that the companies who make modern plugins might have written conversion routines from the old Netscape API

@g00se Sorry if I result ignorant (which I am), but if I start an Applet using Java Web Start, does it still need to use a browser? From what I know, when the JNLP calls tha Applet on the server, the Java Web Start executes it in a some sort of Appletviewer, not a browser (I only have Chrome installed and it works fine). I only have problems with Open Web Start. Does OWS always need a browser?

That applet expects to use a browser, as I said above. Let's take a step back: that looks like an Oracle Forms applet. I'm assuming your company finds a need for its functionality. I would talk to some Oracle people and ask them about upgrade paths that can provide the same functionality now
